# Where can I download Visual Studio Code Documentation?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Where can I download VSCode full documentation for offline reading? My connection is not very stable for online reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can install and view content for various products and technologies such as Visual Studio, .NET, language reference, SQL Server, Windows Development on your local computer by using [Microsoft Help Viewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/help-viewer/installation?view=vs-2019). It will enable you to download sets of content for offline reading.

Alternatively, many documentation sets on [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/) include a link at the bottom of the table of contents to download a PDF version containing all articles it covers.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using Linux. I'm guessing that Help Viewer only works on windows. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I just checked learn.microsoft.com and there's nothing on VSCode. Again, correct me if I'm wrong,